# Socket not receiving the Message AF_UNIX

Tags: c, linux, shell, sockets, unix

```
       Server Side:
 void getMessage(int aSock){
            int n=0;
            char recvline[1025];
            if ( (n = read(aSock, recvline, 1025) ) <0 ) {
                perror("Erro: Nao recebida Mensagem do Servidor");

                printf("%s",recvline);
            }
        }


    .
    .
    .  ( MAIN FUNCTION with all the sockets declarations etc( Its working )

        for(;;){

            clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
            mysock=accept(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

            if(mysock== -1) { 
                perror(" Falhou a Ligacao "); 
            }
            else {
                if ( (childpid = fork()) < 0 ) {
                    system ("clear");  
                    printf("\t\tServidor: Erro");
                    exit(0);          
                }           
                else if ( childpid == 0 ) {
                    close(serverSocket);        
                    getMessage(mysock); 
                    exit(0);

                }
            }
            close(mysock);
        }
    }
    .
    .

CLIENT SIDE

void socketSender(int idAcont, int aClientId,char aProdnome,int numRestock){
    char buffer[1024];
    int tamanho;
    sprintf(buffer,"%d %d %c %d",idAcont,aClientId,aProdnome,numRestock);
    int sockfd, servlen;
    struct sockaddr_un serv_addr;
    if ((sockfd= socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        perror("erro ao criar socket cliente");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(serv_addr.sun_path, UNIXSTR_PATH);
    servlen = strlen(serv_addr.sun_path) + sizeof(serv_addr.sun_family);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, servlen) < 0)
        perror("erro ao fazer connect no cliente");

    tamanho=strlen(buffer)+1;
    if(write(sockfd,buffer,tamanho)!=tamanho)
        perror("Erro ao escrever no cliente");
    close(sockfd);
}
```

The Server side keeps waiting for the messag in the  for(;;) it creates the mysocket that should get the message from the client with the  socketsender()  but the message doesnt pop up :/ any ideas whats wrong ? thank you in advance

Comment: TCP isn't message oriented, but provides mechanics to transfer a **stream** of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the `fork()`ed off server process not just simply ends?

Your servers's logging code seems misplaced. Shouldn't this:

```
if ((n = read(aSock, recvline, 1025) ) <0 ) {
  perror("Erro: Nao recebida Mensagem do Servidor");
  printf("%s",recvline);
}
```

be:

```
if ( (n = read(aSock, recvline, 1025) ) <0 ) {
  perror("Erro: Nao recebida Mensagem do Servidor");
}
printf("%s",recvline);
```